# How can i add a marker image icon on gmaps.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps

I am using [GMaps.js](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) for a WordPress page. But I want to change the marker icon there. They told to use `$('<img/>').attr('src', url)
  .appendTo('#map');`

My current Code `

```
var map;

$(document).ready(function(){
  map = new GMaps({
    el: '#map',
    lat: -12.043333,
    lng: -77.028333
  });

  map.addMarker({
    lat: -12.042,
    lng: -77.028333,
    title: 'Marker with InfoWindow',
    infoWindow: {
      content: '<p>HTML Content</p>'
    }
  });
});
```

Now how can I include a PNG icon as marker image there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go here: http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/documentation.html#GMaps-addMarkers, search 'createMarker'.

Here it says that createMarkers accepts any options from google.maps.markerOptions. Follow this link: [google.maps.markerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions)

It says 'icon' in the list. So add an icon property with the url to your image.

Right below createMarker is addMarker. It accepts the same parameters as createMarker.

This should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: I know that this is on the docs, but you could add it into your answer, so people don't have to go there and look into it all over again...

Comment: Isn't that what I did? Add 'icon' property with a url to your image to addMarker. I suppose I could make it a little more clear or re-order the text.